# Como remover uma coluna do grid usando jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um grid onde tenho que deixar uma coluna oculta, estou fazendo desta forma mais não está fazendo da forma que gostaria porque não tenho como prever quantas linhas vai ter nesta coluna.

Tenho um grid, onde no typename tenho : 


Quero remover a coluna inteira onde tenha este typename especifico

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Matheus Piscioneri</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(document.getElementsByTagName('th')[21]).hide()
                $(document.getElementsByTagName('td')[21]).hide()
              });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <th typename="aprovacaoAprovadorExtra" style="cursor: default" title="Aprovação - Aprovador Extra">
        </th>

        <td class="">Não </td>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: e como sabes qual a linha oculta ?

Comment: Quero ocultar a coluna 21

Comment: Tenho um grid, então eu consigo remover a coluna th mais no caso do td não tenho como saber quantas linhas vai ter no grid

Comment: mas o que a coluna 21 tem de diferente das outras?

Comment: cada coluna tem um ex:  typename="aprovacaoGerencia"

Comment: @itasouza coloque a informaçao toda necessária para respondermos a esta pergunta. Esta pergunta, como está, está incompreensível.

Comment: @itasouza, nós precisamos de alguma coisa que só a coluna 21 vai ter para poder identificar ela, caso ela não tenha uma informação exclusiva será impossível fazer o que você quer...

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma que você pode fazer para esconder todas as colunas das linhas é iterar por elas. Fiz um exemplo para que você possa ter a lógica como base e poder adequar ao seu cenário:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var coluna = 1;
  $(document.getElementsByTagName('th')[coluna]).hide()

  document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(function(a) {
    $(a.querySelectorAll("td")[coluna]).hide();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Defini a variável `coluna` para que ele esconda todas as culunas definidas ali.

Comment: não deu certo, porque eu não tenho uma tabela comum, o td não fica na mesma estrutura

Comment: Como assim? Desculpe, não entendi @itasouza

Answer (score 0):

Com base no código do Lucas (+1), coloquei um botãozinho passando o índice da coluna e transformei em função:

```js
  function ocultar_coluna(coluna)
  {
   $(document.getElementsByTagName('th')[coluna]).hide();
   
   var linhas = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].querySelectorAll('tr');
   
   for (var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++) 
   {
    var colunas = linhas[i].querySelectorAll('td');
    $(colunas[coluna]).hide()
   }
  }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Coluna 0 <input type="button" onclick="ocultar_coluna(0)" value="Ocultar"></th>
          <th>Coluna 1 <input type="button" onclick="ocultar_coluna(1)" value="Ocultar"></th>
          <th>Coluna 2 <input type="button" onclick="ocultar_coluna(2)" value="Ocultar"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>0</td>  
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>0</td>  
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```